# Button Click and Command Precedence

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

```
<Button Height="40" Width="40" x:Name="btnup" Command="{Binding UpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}" Click="Btnup_OnClick">
```

The thing thats happening with this code is, Command is being executed after OnClick. Is it possible to execute Command first and then OnClick. Please help....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, WPF evaluates `OnClick` before invoking `Execute` on a bound command.

Depending on what the click handler does; you could invoke it from `Execute` instead, or raise an event back to the view model, which then raises an event back to the view, which then executes the code.

Something like:

**Code-Behind:**

```
  public SomeViewClass
  {
     public SomeViewClass()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         SomeViewModel viewModel = new SomeViewModel;
         DataContext = viewModel;
         viewModel.SomeCommandCompleted += MoveUp;
     }

     private void MoveUp()
     {
         ...
     }
  }
```

**View Model**

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public event Action SomeCommandCompleted;
    public ICommand SomeCommand {get; private set;}

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        SomeCommand = new DelegateCommand((o) => 
        {
            ...
            if (SomeCommandCompleted != null)
                SomeCommandCompleted();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bradley.. Please take a look at this link.  http://www.morkeleb.com/2009/08/18/wpf-command-execution-and-click-event-execution-on-buttons/
In this case do I have make my ViewModel implement ObservableCommand or MainWindow.cs do it. If ViewModel does, how can I access UI element in the ViewModel.

Comment: Commands typically go in the ViewModel; but you can have the ViewModel raise an event so as to avoid "direct" knowledge of the View. The view would then react to the event as if the button had been pressed.

Comment: Hey Bradley could you please help me with this
 private void MoveUp(object obj){ }
How do I call ButtonOn Click Delegate in the MoveUp Command in the ViewModel. Please write a sample code.

Comment: Bradley Im unable to see the code. Could you please repost.

Comment: @nikhil Well *I* can see the code... Perhaps clear your cache? If the issue persists; perhaps you should post a bug on meta.

Comment: Thanks Bradley Im able to see.